# Why does MPC4725 DAC output in range 0-3.3V when VREF is 5V?

Tags: raspberry-pi, adafruit, mcp4725

I am trying to produce a 0-5V variable output from a Raspberry Pi using:

1. adafruit MCP4725 DAC breakout (https://www.adafruit.com/product/935)
2. SparkFun PCA9306 level translator breakout (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15439) to shift between the Pi 3.3V logic and the 5V I want at the MCP4725

Between GND and VIN/VREF on the MCP4725 breakout I have 5.17V, but with the DAC raw value set at maximum 4095, I have only 3.23V between GND and VOUT.  Varying the DAC raw value does vary VOUT but between 0-3.23V.  All connections seem good visually.

To debug I have tried running the VIN/VREF from 3.3V rail which gives 3.26V between GND and VIN/VREF but maximum 2.12V between GND and VOUT.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: circuit diagram]

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mcp4725
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
dac = adafruit_mcp4725.MCP4725(i2c)

dac.raw_value = 4095  # (0-4095)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the schematic link of PCA9306 is the "same" (5 pins at right)? https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/PCA9306_Breakout.pdf

Comment: So the right ground is not connected ... Connect it on the left ground of PCA9306.

Comment: This is the schematic of the PCA9306 breakout I'm using, it has 5 pins at right, I'm not using the top EN pin.
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/0/1/7/0/9/SparkFun_Level_Translator_PCA9306.pdf

Comment: The left and right ground are connected through the PCB of the PCA9306 breakout.  I have just validated that and also tried connecting the two with a jumper as you suggested but the result is the same.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is interesting that the ratio of Vout to Vref is the same in both cases - 63%. What are the outputs at midscale?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that DAC voltage output is dependent of Rload (must be > 5 kOhm, fig 2-15).

Comment: So it is, thanks so much!